# T1 Line Proper Setup, Routers

Tags: router, t1, networking

I'm a webguy, not a server guy -- but I'm working in an office that just got a T1 line installed.  It comes into the house via a glass covered box with Adtran logos on it with 4 ethernet sockets underneath it.  I'm supposed to use socket one to get my internet connection, since we only have one IP coming into the house.

We have gotten no instructions from Verizon, but we got a big blue Adtran AltaVanta (or something) router in the mail.  If I hook this router up to the T1 box (using their special ethernet cable) then I get a green light on the WAN, which tells me internet is coming into the house just fine.  My issue is that I can't seem to connect to the router properly with my computer to make the necessary settings changes.

I'm wondering if I have to use this Adtran router with the T1 box, or if I can use any router I please (with the special ethernet cable) as long as I use the proper IP/DNS settings Verizon sent to us.  Maybe this Adtran router is special in some way, but if it's not then I'd just rather use my Apple Airport.  Figured I'd ask you guys since I'm weak in this area.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**THOSE ARE NOT ETHERNET JACKS!**

The four ports under the glass covered box (the smart jack) are NOT ethernet jacks - they're RJ45, yes (that's the name for the 8-pin physical plug that ethernet uses), but the are actually running (possibly analog) T1 protocols, not ethernet.  Plugging an ethernet device into them risks damaging the device or the smart jack or both.

You'll need to keep the the Adtran in the way to 'translate' to ethernet.

Comment: Ya, I definitely plugged ethernet stuff into that jack.  Hope I didn't screw something up.

Comment: Actually, ethernet uses 8P8C connectors, not RJ45.

Comment: True, but a distinction lost through use.  It would be hard to get a true RJ45 connector (unless you know where to look).  If the jacks in the Adtran box are T1 lines then the connector is RJ48.  @swt83 - Is it a NetVanta access device?  If so what model?

Comment: @dbasnett: True enough. I just like to point it out in case someone takes it literally and actually wires it as an RJ45.

Answer (score 2):

The clear box on the wall is the smart jack. You will definitely need to plug the Adtran router into that. Usually, you are not able to configure anything on the ISP provided router, as it is (usually) pre-configured. Verizon should have sent you your public IP information, which you would configure your own internal router with. The config would look like this:

Smart Jack > ISP Provided router > Your router/firewall > your network

Comment: The above definitely is making an assumption that "your router" is also a firewall.

Comment: @Miles, added that info.

Answer (score 0):

That Adtran device probably has two interfaces.  One for the T1 which goes to the smart jack and one for your internal LAN.  Typically, when the ISP provides the router it is managed by them.  Give them a call regarding setup to get NAT configured.  This is not like setting up a Linksys router.  You will need their help.  You will then plug in a switch to the Adtran's Ethernet interface and subsequently each computer into the switch.